# Call to a member function toOptionArray() on boolean error when custom dropdown source model is used in system.xml

Tags: module, magento-1, adminhtml, system-config, source-model

My application is configurable, so I have a few settings in the `system.xml` file. One of the setting uses a custom adminhtml dropdown source model.

So, in the XML, I have defined the setting row like this:

```
<store_id translate="label">
    <label>Select Store View</label>
    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
    <source_model>mymodule_adminhtml/system_config_source_dropdown_stores</source_model>
    <comment>Select the store view that is used for the integration.</comment>
    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</store_id>
```

So, I have created the dropdown source model `Stores.php` here:

```
app/code/local/Mycompany/Mymodule/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Source/Dropdown/Stores.php
```

This file's contents are:

```
class Mycompany_Mymodule_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Dropdown_Stores
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        // Build Option Array
        $optionArray = array();
        foreach (Mage::app()->getStores() as $store) {
            $optionArray[] = array(
                'value' => $store->getId(),
                'label' => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__($store->getName())
            );
        }

        // Finished
        return $optionArray;
    }
}
```

My `config.xml` section for defining the models looks like this:

```
<models>
    <mymodule>
        <class>Mycompany_Mymodule_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>mymodule_mysql4</resourceModel>
    </mymodule>
    <mymodule_mysql4>
        <class>Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Mysql4</class>
        <entities>
            <setup>
                <table>mymodule_setup</table>
            </setup>
        </entities>
    </mymodule_mysql4>
</models>
```

This was working fine before. I could go into System -> Config and click on my module tab and I could see a dropdown list of stores.

Today, this isn't working & I am not sure why. I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on boolean in
>   /home/www-data/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form.php
>   on line 463

Any ideas what might have gone wrong? If I comment out the config section row in the `system.xml` the config page works in the backend.

Answer (score 2):

From looking in your part of the `config.xml` codes I can see module calling problem in `system.xml`

```
<source_model>mymodule_adminhtml/system_config_source_dropdown_stores</source_model>
```

Change to

```
<source_model>mymodule/system_config_source_dropdown_stores</source_model>
```

And also change the path of your this file and change class name as well:

```
class Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_System_Config_Source_Dropdown_Stores
```

**Magento strongly follows folder and file structure.** You should match it's requirement exactly to be able to get it work.

**[UPDATE]**

Magento module folder structure should be this:

```
\app\code\local\MyNamespace\Appname\Model
\app\code\local\MyNamespace\Appname\Block
\app\code\local\MyNamespace\Appname\Helper
\app\code\local\MyNamespace\Appname\etc
\app\code\local\MyNamespace\Appname\controllers
etc
```

This means your `adminhtml` cannot come before `model or block or etc` folders. It should/must go inside them.

**To your problem**

When declaring a source model for a field in system.xml, Magento will try to retrieve the options for the field by calling:

```
Mage::getModel('source model here')->toOptionArray();
```

So in your case it tries :

```
Mage::getModel('mymodule_adminhtml/system_config_source_dropdown_stores')->toOptionArray();
```

and returns null.

> If I changed it like you said, then the file's location must be moved. I tried it anyway and still same error.

Then there is something wrong in your `Model/System/Config/Source/Dropdown/Stores.php` file. Try replacing this function and see if that works for debugging:

```
public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            //array('value'=>'', 'label'=>''),
            array('value'=>'grid', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Grid Only')),
            array('value'=>'list', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('List Only')),
            array('value'=>'grid-list', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Grid (default) / List')),
            array('value'=>'list-grid', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('List (default) / Grid')),
        );
    }
```

Comment: P.s is there a built in dropdown source I could use (like the adminhtml yes/no) to retrieve a list of stores configured in the magento rather than implementing it myself?

Comment: Actually, I did some digging around turns out there is a built in store list model. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. I did not implement my own custom dropdown source model, instead I used one of the built in ones. This is what I did:

Changed:

```
<source_model>mymodule_adminhtml/system_config_source_dropdown_stores</source_model>
```

To:

```
<source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_store</source_model>
```

and voilà, it works. This is good enough for me, I don't need to re-invent the wheel to get a dropdown list of `store id => name`.

Answer (score 0):

> Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on boolean in
>   /home/www-data/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form.php
>   on line 463

Above error is coming because your compilation is enable. So please follow bellow `steps`

1. Go admin side System > Tools > Compilation page and click on Disable button.
2. Go admin side System > Cache Management screen and use Flush Cache button.
3. Now check again.